# Which method of sending SMS in Android is better

Tags: android, android-intent

I know there are two ways of sending sms in Android:

1. Using SMS manager
2. Using intent with action SEND_TO

Can someone explain how sending sms using intent works? Following is what I think/know about it:
When we send sms using intent then it sends intent to the default sms app and then default sms app send the sms using the SmsManager.

Please correct me if I am wrong or in case there is other information.

Which method of sending sms is popular among current sms apps in Android market? or among any other app which wants to send sms?

Comment: Why people are down voting this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Types)

`When you create an implicit intent, the Android system finds the appropriate component to start by comparing the contents of the intent to the intent filters declared in the manifest file of other apps on the device. If the intent matches an intent filter, the system starts that component and delivers it the Intent object. If multiple intent filters are compatible, the system displays a dialog so the user can pick which app to use.`

So when you send the sms using intent first it check for the apps which can handle the message and opens the appropriate application. If multiple application are there it will give the app chooser dialog to select the app.

**Which method of sending sms is popular among current sms apps in Android market?**

It depends on your application requirement. If your application wants to handle the sending of message use SMSManager or if u want to give the choice to user to select sending app use the intents.